# Oracle create table to handle valid_from and valid_to data

Tags: oracle, create-table

I am in the middle of designing a table which include two columns valid_from and valid_to to track historical changes. For example, my table structure is like below:

```
create table currency_data
(
 currency_code varchar(16) not null,
 currency_desc varchar(16) not null,
 valid_from date not null,
 valid_to date,
 d_insert_date date,
 d_last_update date,
 constraint pk_currency_data primary key (currency_code, valid_from)
)
```

The idea is to leave the valid_to as blank to start with, and if the currency_desc changes in the future, I will need to set a valid_to to the date that the old description is not valid any more, and create a new rows with a new valid_from. But how can I ensure that there will be never a overlap between these 2 rows. For example the query below should only yield one row.

```
select currency_desc
  from currency_data
 where currency_code = 'USD'
   and trunc(sysdate) between valid_from and nvl(valid_to, sysdate)
```

Is there a better way to achieve this please other than make sure all developers/end users aware of this rule. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a set of implementation approaches known as [`slowly changing dimensions (SCD)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension) for handling this kind of storage.

What you are currently implementing is SCD II, however, there are more.

Regarding your possible interval overlap issue - there is no simple way to enforce table-level (instead of row-level) consistency with standard constraints, so I guess a robust approach would be to restrict direct DML to this table and wrap it into some standartized pl/sql API which will enforce your riles prior to insert/update and which every developer will use.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. You're right I am implementing SCD II but just wondering is there a way we can force the check with constraints or triggers that I am not aware of.

Comment: @CanLu you might also find this thread useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468327/implementing-table-level-check-constraint/13469096#13469096